Indexing Manager shows incorrect output after reindex finished successfully
I am testing a Sitecore 10.3.1 site, and whenever I perform a reindex, I see this output in the Indexing Manager:
Job started: {0}
Job ended: {0} (units processed: {1})

Finished in 65 seconds


It looks like Sitecore isn't replacing the string placeholders {0} properly.
I am not seeing anything unusual in the Sitecore logs:
37184 18:30:09 INFO  AUDIT (sitecore\Admin): Rebuild indexes from Indexing Manager: sitecore_master_index

...

ManagedPoolThread #14 12:59:42 INFO  Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_master_index

...

ManagedPoolThread #8 17:56:01 INFO  Job ended: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_master_index (units processed: 37355)

This was working previously on my 9.0.2 instance.
Where should I be looking to troubleshoot the issue?

What did Sitecore Support say?

As Michael West said, this is a Sitecore Support case, and you might get an answer from them about this.

The issue was caused by an old patch config:
<configuration>
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <!-- Removing the whole getTranslation pipeline and re-adding empty one to get rid of the errors in logs -->
      <getTranslation>
        <patch:delete/>
      </getTranslation>
      <getTranslation />      
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>

Ultimately, this patch appears to render Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.Text() useless, whether the call is made in Sitecore's code or custom code.
What's notable is that this patch didn't produce this adverse effect on Sitecore v9.0.2.
This patch has also been a source of other issues.
I researched where this code came from and discovered what appears to be its origin; from Sitecore themselves, all the way back in May 2015: https://github.com/Sitecore/configs/commit/3be6a2475310239183d5894f33f67a454af7a107
Alex Ewerlöf sums up the moral of this story:

Bugs’ genitals are called copy & paste. That’s how they reproduce. Always read what you copy, always audit what you import.

